# how to disable split screen view

Tags: android

I have a problem where my customers are using an old version of my Android app, this is because the server-side application needs upgrading to the latest version before they can have the latest version of the Android app which implements the ActionBarActivity.

All has worked well until Android 6, when the user presses or long presses the recents apps button, there used to be a menu floating up. This has now gone as of Android 6 and split screen mode is in its place.

Is there a way to disable the split screen mode so that the old style menu can be used?

thanks

Comment: "This has now gone as of Android 6 and split screen mode is in its place" -- not in standard Android. The N Developer Preview has this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi Mark, my phone is running 6.0.1 Marshmellow. Is there some setting i can change to bring the old gingerbread style menu back?

Comment: Ask the phone manufacturer.